# Connectors on pH electrodes

Tags: bnc, electrode

I would like to know why pH electrodes are always with BNC type connectors (or DIN, S7, etc.), but never with "simple" wires.

Can we put a BNC adapter to 2 wires and read the tensions with a multimeter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

pH probes basically act as batteries, just with very high internal resistance (giga-Ohm range). With such high internal resistance the signal is very "weak", so shielded cable is used to reduce interference. BNC connector also shields the signal, so it is a good choice. [Making a measurement circuit is not trivial](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa529a/snoa529a.pdf). For example: you have to take PCB leakage into consideration.

The probe voltage is too low and its internal resistance is too high to be directly read with a multimeter.